# how do I get a single value from firebase using angularfire2 and angular5?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular5

I am trying to obtain and display a single value from firebase.

My firebase structure looks like this:
[image]

My current .ts file looks like:

```
storestat$: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {
     this.storestat$ = afDb.list<any>('MyShop').snapshotChanges();
}
```

I want to display the storeStatus value within the html using {{}} binding. Something like the following:

```
<button>{{ storeStatus }} Status</button>
```

I tried using the following initially:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let s of storestat$ | async">...
<button>{{ s.storeStatus }}</button>
```

but of course that wouldn't work.

I tried searching for answers but they just didn't seem quite relevant as they were all pointing to obtaining multiple specific values from lists.

I am using angularfire2 and angular5.

I am new to angular5 so any help would be appreciated, including any educational pointers.

Comment: to debug try `<p>{{ s | json }}</p>` and check the data is coming?

Comment: I get the following error:
AppComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at JsonPipe.transform (common.js:5954)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:4)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:13790)...

Comment: try with `.valueChanges()` method.

Comment: that gives the same error as well. I have a solution posted below but I think it is a little messy.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround but not sure if it is the best solution. my new .ts file relevant portion looks like:

```
    this.storestat$ = afDb.list<any>('myshop').snapshotChanges()
       .map(
            changes => {
               return changes.map(
                  c => ({ val: c.payload.val(), 
                          key: c.payload.key,
                          ...c.payload.val()
                   })
               );
       });
```

and my .html relevant portion now looks like:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let s of storestat$ | async">

  <button *ngIf="s.key == 'storeStatus'">{{ s.val }} Status</button>

</ng-container>
```

I don't think this is the cleanest solution as the database call maps the unwanted Current Orders branch as well, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not care about the push keys you can use `.valueChanges()` and it should work like this

```
afDb.list<any>('myshop').valueChanges().subscribe(value => 
{
    this.storestat$ = value;
});
```

and in html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let s of storestat$">

  <button>{{ s.storeStatus }} Status</button>

</ng-container>
```

Comment: I thought that would work, but it doesn't. For whatever reason the value of storeStatus is not passed through as it should be. This is why I had to explicitly map the values in my solution below.

Comment: can you show the full structure of myshop. only a part shown in your image

Comment: I have modified my original post to show the full structure of myshop

Comment: is `storeStatus` under `CurrentOrders`?

Comment: i am not sure why its not working. i have changed my answer with subcription. try this with out async pipe.

Comment: storeStatus is outside of CurrentOrders.

Comment: I get the error AppComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.

However, if I use {{ s }} and let it print every loop then it does print the value I am after but it also includes [object Object] which is the Current Orders branch

Comment: may be `*ngFor` has problems with objects try parsing `this.storestat$ = JSON.parse(value)`